# "failed to get to process -1"

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

i have this big problem with my iOS Developer (i guess).
Sometimes (every 2 or 3 times) when i run my app on my iPhone 5S it stops and the error "failed to get to process -1" appears. After that my iPhone is stuck and frozen and i have to reset it (Power + HomeButton). I searched through the web and found that it has something to do with the Code Signing. 
Something like "Only use iOS Developer" and "code signing entitlements only for debug" i tried like every variant with this, but without success. It is kind of weird, because all the others with the same problem seem to have it all the time. My iPhone only gets stuck every now and then.
I have already reseted it to defaults and tried it again, no success. I deleted the Provisioning Profile and add it again, but again with no success.
It's a real pain.
Here is a screenshot of my settings that i used to use:
[image]

And here the error:
[image]

I did nothing, it just occurred and it happens in every project, 
Can you guys help me? I am really tired of this problem and i am not able to find a solution.
I am running XCode 5.0.1 on the latest OS X Mavericks. On my iPhone 5S i have the latest iOS 7.0.3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not see you using any developer certificate/provisioning profile to sign the app before running it on your iPhone 5s? Do you have a developer certificate and profile? (You can not debug your app on an iOS device without these, AFAIK).

Comment: Yes, i have one. And like i said, it used to work. I was able to debug without problems. And yes, my developer account is still active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here, seems related to xcode 5.0.1. Rolling back to 5.0.0 solved the issue.